# How to make contributions to open source?

Tags: .net, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pick an open source project to join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532352/how-to-pick-an-open-source-project-to-join)

I am a c# programmer with a little over 2 years of experience in developing mostly web applications. I enjoy occationaly working on php and designing and developing frontend. 
I would like to share my skills and knowledge to the opensource projects even though I'm not yet a programming guru.

How did you start contributing on open source?
What is the best way to start when you don't have one of your own?

Edit: I've seen in the related questions that writing documentation is one of the way. Unfortunately not mine as English is not my first language. Also I would appreciate on answers related to .net 4's.

Answer (score 5):

Is there an open source project (tool, library, whatever) that you frequently use in your own work? You could start by contacting people involved in its development.

Comment: Even better if you supply patches to fix bugs that annoy you or support functionality you want in those tools. Bonus points for following any CodingStyle files they may have included :)